# How does the css px unit map to the actual device pixel?

Tags: css

Below is the html code.

```
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .my {
      border: 2px solid;
      width: 414px;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .right {
      text-align: right
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>this is the ...</h2>

  <div class="my">abc</div>
  <div class="right">this is the right</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see the 414 pixel div is there
[image]

I know the devicePixelRatio is 3, so the actual pixel of width is about 414 * 3 pixel. But when I set width to 414 pixel in css, why it occupy about 2/5 of the width? How does the css pixel map to the actual pixel?

Another attached.
[image]
Why I need to set 960px to fill the width of iphone 6plus?

Comment: I think this has less to do with pixel scaling and more to do with viewport scaling. By default, Safari on iOS (I don't know about others) tends to zoom the page out to accommodate traditional desktop sites being too wide to fit a smaller screen. What if you set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`?

Comment: I agree with @BoltClock . Use `meta` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `viewport` `metatag` to control the layout on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

For more help on `viewport` read this [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        .my {
            border: 2px solid;
            width: 414px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        .right {
            text-align: right
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>this is the ...</h2>

    <div class="my">abc</div>
    <div class="right">this is the right</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are missing this metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Why would you doubt that? It looks like that is exactly what he's missing.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt unfortunately I missed the meta tag in the answer. Have edited the post now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need to use viewport meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```